# Find string in list of splitted string

Tags: python, string

I have a string `teststring` and a list of substrings `s` but where the `teststring` was accidentally split. Now I would like to know the indexes within the list, which, if put together, would recreate the `teststring`.

```
teststring = "Hi this is a test!"

s = ["Hi", "this is", "Hello,", "Hi", "this is", "a test!", "How are", "you?"]
```

The expected output would be (the strings in the list `s` that would make up the `teststring` need to appear consecutively ->  `[0,4,5]` would be wrong):

```
[3,4,5]
```

**Anyone knows how to do that ?**

I *tried* to come up with a decent solution, but found nothing that was working...

I just record every instance that a part of the `teststring` appears in one of the substrings in `s`:

```
test_list = []
for si in s:
    if si in teststring:
        flag = True

    else:
        flag = False
    test_list.append(flag)
```

Then you would get: `[True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False]`
...and then one would have to take the index of the longest consecutive "True". Anayone knows how to get those indexes ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be [0,4,5]?  Also, looks like homework, could you show what you tried or what you considered?

Comment: @BillK Good point ! Forgot to mention that the strings need to appear consecutively, so one cannot jump between strings in the list. It's not homework. :) I added my attempt.

Comment: You say *the teststring was accidentally split*: You're asking how to write a program to fix a bug in another program. Don't do it. Fix that other program.

Comment: @BoarGules Can't do it. It's not my program. :( I just received the strings like that. On the upside: It's a little programming challenge. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is a list of consecutive indices that form the string when concatenated, I think this will do what you're looking for:

```
teststring = "Hi this is a test!"

s = ["Hi", "this is", "Hello,", "Hi", "this is", "a test!", "How are", "you?"]

test_list = []
i = 0 # the index of the current element si
for si in s:
    if si in teststring:
        # add the index to the list
        test_list.append(i)

        # check to see if the concatenation of the elements at these 
        # indices form the string. if so, this is the list we want, so exit the loop
        if ' '.join(str(s[t]) for t in test_list) == teststring:
            break
    else:
        # if we've hit a substring not in our teststring, clear the list because
        # we only want consecutive indices
        test_list = []

    i += 1
```

Comment: Very nice ! Accepted this as answer, since it is efficient as it does not go through the entire list when it has found the concatenated substring.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little convoluted, but it does the job:

```
start_index = ' '.join(s).index(teststring)
s_len = 0
t_len = 0
indices = []
found = False
for i, sub in enumerate(s):
    s_len += len(sub) + 1 # To account for the space
    if s_len > start_index:
        found = True
    if found:
        t_len += len(sub)
        if t_len > len(teststring):
            break
        indices.append(i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Join the list into a large string, find the target string in the large string, then determine the starting and ending indices by checking the length of each string in the list.

```
>>> teststring = "Hi this is a test!"
>>> s = ["Hi", "this is", "Hello,", "Hi", "this is", "a test!", "How are", "you?"]
>>> joined = ' '.join(s)
>>> index = joined.index(teststring)
>>> lengths = list(map(len, s))
>>> loc = 0
>>> for start,ln in enumerate(lengths):
...     if loc == index:
...             break
...     loc += ln + 1
...
>>> dist = 0
>>> for end,ln in enumerate(lengths, start=start):
...     if dist == len(teststring):
...         break
...     dist += ln + 1
...
>>> list(range(start, end))
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Very nice method ! Thanks a lot for sharing this idea !

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach the problem, hope it helps:

```
def rebuild_string(teststring, s):
    for i in range(len(s)): # loop through our whole list
        if s[i] in teststring:
            index_list = [i] # reset each time
            temp_string = teststring
            temp_string = temp_string.replace(s[i], "").strip()
            while i < len(s) - 1: # loop until end of list for each run through for loop
                if len(temp_string) == 0: # we've eliminated all characters
                    return index_list # all matches are found, so we'll break all our loops and exit
                i += 1 # we need to manually increment i inside while loop, but reuse variable because we need initial i from for loop
                if s[i] in temp_string: # the next item in list is also in our string
                    index_list.append(i)
                    temp_string = temp_string.replace(s[i], "").strip()
                else:
                    break # go back to for loop and try again
    return None # no match exists in the list

my_test = "Hi this is a test!"

list_of_strings = ["Hi", "this is", "Hello,", "Hi", "this is", "a test!", "How are", "you?"]


print(rebuild_string(my_test, list_of_strings))
```

Result:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Basically I just found where the list item exists in the main string, and then the next successive list items must also exist in the string, until there is nothing left to match (stripping white spaces along the way). This would match strings that are put in the list out of order too, so long as when they are combined they recreate the entire string. Not sure if that's what you were going for though...